# cakephp send and get json

Tags: php, cakephp

i have tag in cakephp like this:

```
var url_save = "<?php echo $this->Html->url(array('controller' => 'users','action' => 'save_template')) ;?>";
     $.ajax({
    url  : url_save,
    type : "POST",
    data : JSON.stringify(templates),
    dataType : 'json'
     });
```

how the controller can take the data value?

Comment: Firstly make clear what you want to do ??

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$this->request->data` on the Controller the usual way.

Answer (score 0):

you can get json data using `$this->data` in controller, you can check if the request is ajax if you want using `$this->RequestHandler->isAjax()` but you must also add `RequestHandler` in component variable.